# How to draw $U$ such that $ \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} = 0$ for $(x,y) \in U$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There is a function $G = xy - \frac{x^a}{a} - \frac{y^b}{b}$, $x,y \geq 0 $ and $a > 1$, $b > 1$, $ a - 1 = \frac{1}{b-1}$.
 I need to draw a set $U = \{ (x,y) | \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = 0 $ and $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y} = 0 \}$ and calculate value of $G$ at that points of $U$. Since these are partial derivatives I could calculate, say, $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$ considering $y$ as a constant, find a first set A which consists of such $x$, then I would do the same for $y$ and it would be set $B$. Does it mean that $U$ is a cartesian product of sets $A$ and $B$? Or another approach can be used here?

Comment: Typo... Right, I should be $-\frac{y^b}{b}$, my bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $U$ is not a cartesian product. Being the solution set of the two equations
$${\partial G\over\partial x}=y-x^{a-1}=0,\qquad {\partial G\over\partial y}=x-y^{b-1}=0\tag{1}$$
one would expect that $U$ is the set of intersection points of two curves, hence a hopefully finite set of isolated points. Due to special circumstances this is not the case here: Since $a-1={1\over b-1}$ both equations $(1)$ describe the same curve. Therefore
$$U=\bigl\{(x,y)\bigm| x\geq0, \ y=x^{a-1}\bigr\}\ .$$
Concerning the value of $G$ on the points of $U$ this value is constant: If $t\mapsto \bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$ is a parametrization of $U$ we have to look at
$\phi(t):=G\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$, and the chain rule tells us that $$\phi'(t)={\partial G\over\partial x}x'(t)+{\partial G\over\partial y}y'(t)\equiv0\ .$$
It follows that
$$G(x,y)=G(1,1)=1-{1\over a}-{1\over b}\qquad\bigl((x,y)\in U\bigr)\ .$$

Comment: Could you please comment on the last line: is it true that any constant value could be substituted into $G$ instead of $1$?

Comment: @student: I took the point $(1,1)\in U$ in order to simplify the calculations. One could have taken another point in $U$, e.g., the point $(2,2^{a-1})$.